# Why is my car jumping while I drive?

Tags: engine, electrical, manual-transmission, mitsubishi, eclipse

So for a while now, my car has been jumping back and forth like its stalling when I take off and barely stays alive when I'm at a stop.

I got the purge valve checked up and it ran fine for awhile then it acted up while I went up a hill.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

My car is a 1999 Mitsubishi Eclipse manual transmission.

Comment: Is your check engine light on?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities that could cause such an issue,  these include plugs, ignition leads, coil failure etc. 
Also vacuum leaks due to cracked perished hoses etc can lead to issues like this. 
Checking for any OBD engine codes would be the first place to start.